# Sum of energy from torques of several disks in double rotation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, rotational-dynamics, homework-and-exercises

**Here the study:**

An external system (not drawn) give energy for rotate disks around themselves and around green axis. All disks have energy at start, at $t=0$ friction is ON and at $t=0$ external system is OFF (it don't add energy to disks). I think this energy must be conserved in this case.

2 Layers of red disks turn at $w_1$ clockwise around green axis (center of the image). All red disks are link together with green stems. All red disks turn at $w_2$ anticlockwise around their center of gravity for the first layer and at $w_2'$ anticlockwise around their center of gravity for the second layer. There is force F when disks touch another one. Red disk touch disk side by side but it is only at the 4 corners that disks touch layer1/layer2.

[image]

*$R$ = Radius of first square layer (a side of inside square = 2R)

$r$ = radius of red disk

$F$ = basic force from friction

$t$ = time

$w_2' < w_2 $

$R = 6r  $*
$w_1 > w_2$

[image]

**I compute work from torques:**

There are 24 disks inside and 32 disks outside.

- Disks: +24+32+8 torques on red disks = $Frt( 48(w_1-w_2)+64(w_1-w_2')+8(w_1-w_2)+8(w_1-w_2')$
- Friction : $+ 24Fr(w_2+w_2)t + 32Fr(w_2'+w_2')t + 8Fr(w_2+w_2')t $
- Corners: -8 torques layer1 - 8 torque layer2 $= -8(R+2r)Fw_1t -8(R+2r)Fw_1t= -8(6r+2r)Fw_1t-64Frw_1t = -128Frw_1t$

The sum of works from torque = $128Frtw_1-56Frtw_2-72Frtw_2' +56Frtw_2+72Frtw_2' -128Frw_1t$

The sum = 0

All is fine !

**All forces from friction for watch where there is contact**

[image]

I hope I don't forgot one :)

**All force**

[image]

**Zoom of a corner**

[image]

**Disks can be like that:**

[image]

**And this give the possibility for composed friction :**

[image]

Comment: What drives the disks?

Comment: I reply in the question, it's an external system that give energy just before t=0. At t=0, friction is ON. And at t=0 the external system is OFF.

Comment: I added all informations I can, what's wrong with my question ? It's because it is too specific ? But I don't find another question in this field in Physics ST or another forum in Google.

Comment: 2nd law applies to isolated systems, and when you have friction it is no longer and isolated system (unless you are capturing the heat generated).

Comment: After t=0, the system is isolated. Nothing add energy to it. True, I count the energy from heating generating by itself. The energy must be conserved, with one layer only my method works.

Comment: If two disks are contacting each other, then the clockwise rotation of one induces a *counter*-clockwise rotation in the other. So unless you are driving the rotation of those disks, this will not work.

Comment: Disks will change their rotationnal velocity, but in a very short time and with a low friction, the sum of energy must be constant too. With low friction, disk don't reverse their direction of rotation, they slow down. The difference 8Frt(w2'-w2) can take in account the difference of velocity, w2' decrease and w2 decrease but the sum for a delta(t) is not 0. Don't forget, if w2 slow down, the energy increase because w1>w2 and energy of each disk is a function of (w1-w2)².